# How to convert dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM string into JavaScript Date object by vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I try this by vue.js but I get date.getTime not function error.

```
var date = '22/11/2017 17:53'            
var milliseconds = date.getTime();
console.log(milliseconds)
```

Comment: The getTime() method operates on date Objects, so you need to convert your date string to a date object between your 1st en 2nd line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `string#replace` to convert your date string from `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM` format to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. Then, you can convert date from your `changedString`.

```js
const dateString = '22/11/2017 17:53';
const changedDate = dateString.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....) (..):(..)/, '$3-$2-$1 $4:$5');
var date = new Date(changedDate);
console.log(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to make next format "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM".
Thatswhy you need to change your string to the format. If you can't get this value with the right format you need to transform this string for example with next code:

```
var date = '22/11/2017 17:53';
var splittedDate = date.split('/');
date = [splittedDate[1], splittedDate[0], splittedDate[2]].join('/');
```

And then if you have a date with the right format you can parse it:

```
var dateObject = new Date(date);
var milliseconds = dateObject.getMilliseconds();
console.log(milliseconds);
```

Profit